# Get selected value from Combo box

Tags: angularjs, html, rest

I need help with getting a selected value on the combo box and display it. Attached is a piece of code that shows what I've tried.

```
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Issue Type:</label>
<div>
   <select ng-model="selectedIssue" ng-options="task as task.calltypename for task in tasktype"><option value="" >Please Select</option></select>
</div>
```

Comment: the current code will assign the selected object to `selectedIssue` property. If you need to bind the selected value instead of selected object, then `ng-options="task.calltypeid as task.calltypename....`

Comment: @eldix why did you remove the answer?

Comment: I actually wanted the value not the object. Thanks.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I didn't remove any answer, perhaps it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value with

```
Console.log(selectedIssue.calltypename);
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasktype = [{calltypename :'Outbound'},{calltypename :'Internal'}, {calltypename :'Inbound'}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController"> 
<select ng-model="selectedIssue" ng-options="task as task.calltypename for task in tasktype"><option value="" >Please Select</option></select>

<label>Selected type:{{selectedIssue.calltypename}}</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML code, Hope this helps

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedIssue" ng-options="item as item.calltypename for item in names">
</select>
<label>Issue type:{{selectedIssue.calltypename}}</label>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{calltypename:'Emil'},{calltypename:'Emily'}, {calltypename:'Emial'}];
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample :

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="App" >
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">
<select  ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected" ng-change="changedValue(blisterPackTemplateSelected)" 
     data-ng-options="blisterPackTemplate as blisterPackTemplate.name for blisterPackTemplate in blisterPackTemplates">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
{{itemList}}     
  </div>       
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.itemList=[];
    $scope.blisterPackTemplates=[{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"},{id:3,name:"c"}]

    $scope.changedValue=function(item){
    $scope.itemList.push(item.name);
    }    

}
```

**Following is the Output**

[image]

Hope it helps you.